# Observable.concat

Tags: java, android, rxjava2

Имеется 2 источника данных: БД и сервер.
При старте приложения вызывается следующий метод репозитория (MyRepository):

```
public Observable<List<MyObj>> fetchMyObjs() {
    Observable<List<MyObj>> localData = mLocalDataSource.fetchMyObjs();
    Observable<List<MyObj>> remoteData = mRemoteDataSource.fetchMyObjs();
    return Observable.concat(localData, remoteData);
}
```

Подписываюсь на него следующим образом:

```
mMyRepository.fetchMyObjs()         
            .compose(applySchedulers())
            .subscribe(
                    myObjs -> {
                        //do somthing
                    },
                    throwable ->  {
                        //handle error
                    }
            );
```

Я ожидаю, что данные из БД подгрузятся быстрей, а когда завершится загрузка данных из сети, я просто обновлю данные в Activity.

При подключенной сети Интернет все отрабатывает хорошо. Но когда открываем приложение без подключения к сети, то `mRemoteDataSource.fetchMyObjs();` кидает UnknownHostException и на этом все Observable'ы завершаются (подписчик для localData не отрабатывает (хотя логи показывают, что данные из БД были взяты)). И когда я пытаюсь заново вызвать метод `fetchMyObjs()` из класса `MyRepository` (через SwipeRefresh), то подписчик на localData срабатывает.

Как можно добиться того, чтобы при отключенной сети при старте приложения подписчик на localData сработал?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать вместо concat команду [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) или ее варианты

Comment: @Serj , пробовал. Такое же поведение.

Comment: A mergeDelayError ? Тут в любом случае будет приходить ошибка, после которой будете показывать юзеру что нет интернета. А лучше   сделать проверку наличия интернета, а потом вернуть concat(localData, remoteData) или localData

Comment: @Serj , mergeDelayError попробовал, все так же. При старте приложения subscriber не отрабатывает. При повторном вызове метода все норм. Уже и логи напихал везде. По ним видно, что сначала из  бд загружаются данные, а потом сразу onError у subscriber'a срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить `retry(throwable -> true)`

В таком случае, если в каком-то произойдёт ошибка для этого элемента, то последующая цепочка не сработает, в том числе `onError` в `subscribe`.

Если `retry` добавить для `mRemoteDataSource.fetchMyObjs()`, то ошибка будет проигнорирована только для этого Observable. Если добавить после `Observable.concat` то ошибки из базы и/или из сети будут проигнорированы.

В вашем случае, если ошибка от сети не волнует, но нужно получить другие ошибки в `subscribe`, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
public Observable<List<MyObj>> fetchMyObjs () {
    Observable<List<MyObj>> localData = mLocalDataSource.fetchMyObjs();
    Observable<List<MyObj>> remoteData = mRemoteDataSource.fetchMyObjs()
        .retry(throwable -> throwable instanceof IOException);
    return Observable.concat(localData, remoteData);
}
```

Comment: Не хотелось бы игнорировать ошибку  и вывести пользователю ее в snackbar. В общем, я хочу добиться поведения при повторном вызове метода `fetchMyObjs()` т.е. сначала вызов onNext, а затем onError у subscribe.

Comment: Добавьте перед `retry` вызов `doOnError` с обработкой ошибки. Ошибка будет в `doOnError` и в `Subsribe.onError`. Так что если существуют другие ошибки их обработку необходимо будет разделить через `instanceof`.